# Carregar datepicker no modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Bom dia.

Não estou conseguindo carregar o datepicker dentro de um modal chamado via ajax, alguem teria um exemplo de código?

MODAL:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalaltera" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Recuperar Chave de Acesso</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="POST" id="formulario" name='formulario' action="">
            <label>Dia</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                            <input type="text" name='dia2' class="form-control" id="dia2" placeholder="Selecione a Data" required   >
                        </div>

                        <br>


                        <label for="sel1">Horario</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
                            <select class="form-control" id="hora" name="hora" >

                                <option value="" >---</option>

                            </select>
                        </div><br><br> 
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">


            <script src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/js/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default form_submit" onclick="enviarpass(recemail.value)">ENVIAR PALAVRA CHAVE</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function modalaltera(){
    $('#modalaltera').modal('show');
    }

$('#dia2').datepicker({
                    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                    language: 'pt-BR'
                });
```

Obrigado

Comment: Podes mostrar o código que tens e não funciona?

Answer (score 1):

Tente esta solução:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="00/00/0000" id="dia2" />
```

Javascript:

```
$("#dia2").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado', 'Domingo'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
    monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez']
});
```

Comment: Ele reclama que o datepicker não é uma função - (index):318 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: você colocou a referência do datepicker?

Comment: você colocou isto? <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: Coloquei mas não funcionou, parece que o modal não está 'herdando' os scripts

Comment: onde você esta chamado o modal?

Comment: tenho um botão na view consulta.php quando clicado abre um modal com alguns dados e um botão de alterar, esse botao de alterar deverá abrir outro modal para selecionar a data, o script está em outra view chamada footer.php

Comment: tente colocar na mesma view a referencia

Comment: O botao tem o evento onclick para a function: function modalaltera(){
    $('#modalaltera').modal('show');
    
    }

Comment: Não funcionou, mas parou de reclamar que o datepicker não existe

Comment: Qual erro que deu?

Comment: Não apresentou erro, faz sentido ser algo com relacionado o css?

Comment: improvavel, vc já tentou rodar este código no console do navegador ou já deu debug?

Comment: Descobri o erro, era uma div que estava fechando antes do modal rs...Obrigado pelo apoio!